# Some device returns latitude and longitude 0.0

Tags: java, android, android-gps

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private  Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public GPSTracker( ) {

    }
    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Activity Call

```
  GPSTracker   gpsTracker=new GPSTracker(CitymanagerActivity.this);
   if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {

                double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(CitymanagerActivity.this, latitude + " @@@Works@@@ " + longitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Hello. What exactly is your question ?

Comment: Thatś the default value. Maybe devices have not gathered a valid location or service is disabled. Still, you are stating something and we don know what do you intend to do

Comment: Unless you expect your users to be in the Gulf of Guinea, it is an easy situation to detect and handle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082164/115145

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare Sir I am struggling with this problem also, can you help plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767657/how-to-real-time-preview-change-of-video-recorder-on-camera-like-vigo-video-hyps

Answer (score 5):

1)Do not use GPSTracker.  This class has been known to be utterly broken for years.  It works sometimes, but its flawed at the conceptual level in assumptions it makes about location.  I have a blog post about it here:  http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

2)THis is what happens when you assume getLastKnownLocation is valid.  It rarely is.  It should be used only as an optimization, and then inly if you know what you're doing.  The author of GPSTracker didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it takes time to return the lat long. Add one if else condition to check if lat long is 0.0. If lat long is 0 call that method again to get the location. I also faced the same issue so i called the method again and again and after two three hits, it gives the lat longs.

**Note:** GPS Tracker is very old code. Instead of using it you can use Fused api for location.

My code:

```
private void getLatLong() {
        try {
            mLatitudeOrigin = GPSTracker.latitude;
            mLongitudeOrigin = GPSTracker.longitude;

            if (mLatitudeOrigin.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLatitudeOrigin = GPSTracker.latitude;
                        mLongitudeOrigin = GPSTracker.longitude;

                        if (mLatitudeOrigin.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                            getLatLong();
                        }
                        System.out.println("---mLatLngList iterateAllLocation 1---" + mLatLngList);

                    }
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                System.out.println("---mLatLngList iterateAllLocation 2---" + mLatLngList);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```